# ldapsearch fails with TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate

Tags: ldap, openssl, openldap

I'm trying to configure secure LDAP client using the certificates (RootCA, IntermediateCA, IssuingCA and Server certificate) and created the truststore.
`openssl s_client` works successfully but when I run `ldapsearch` I get the below error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
additional info: TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate
```

ldap.conf:

```
SASL_NOCANON    on
#Configration for LDAP
URI ldaps://ldapserver.abc.example.com/
BASE dc=ldapserver,dc=abc,dc=example,dc=com
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts
TLS_CACERT /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

LDAP server FQDN: `ldapserver.abc.example.com`
Client FQDN: `centos7.xyz.example.com`

Do I need to create a new certificate for the client using the provided certificates, if yes how?

Comment: `openssl s_client` by default does not check cert hostname. Try `openssl s_client -connect myldapserver:636 -verify_hostname myldapserver -verify_return_error`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , thank you for your reply. I got  'Verify return code: 62 (Hostname mismatch)' error. I'm using wildcard cert, could that be the reason. If yes, then how can I fix this.

Comment: OpenSSL accepts wildcard cert if it's correct and the wildcard matches the (single) leftmost component as specified in 2830 and 4513 -- and others including 6125. (Actually 4513 allows wildcard only in SAN not CN, but OpenSSL allows both. You _should_ be using SAN this decade.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ,  The wildcard cert has subject alternative name: DNS Name=*.ldapserver.abc.example.com  Is this the right format. If yes, then why does it still say Hostname mismatch 'TLS: hostname (ldapserver.abc.example.com) does not match common name in certificate (Ldap Example).'

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , got it working when I added TLS_REQSAN allow in ldap.conf.

Comment: The wildcard *.ldapserver.abc.example.com does NOT match ldapserver.abc.example.com; it would only match something like xyz.ldapserver.abc.example.com. See the RFCs as I said and/or https://serverfault.com/questions/1047111/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217959/ https://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ . If you're stuck with this cert then yes you'll have to disable checking.

Comment: You should add the TLS_REQSAN comment as an answer. (It's okay to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below property in `ldap.conf` resolved this error:

```
TLS_REQSAN allow
```